# jboss-cli.sh not working on centos 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, centos, wildfly, jboss-cli

I am using Wildfly-12 on  Centos 7. 
When I run   ./jboss-cli.sh got  following error  :

```
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
    java.io.IOException: Error executing 'stty -echo ıntr undef': stty: invalid argument `ıntr'
    Try 'stty --help' for more information.
    : Error executing 'stty -echo ıntr undef': stty: invalid argument `ıntr'
    Try 'stty --help' for more information.
```

and java -version output is   :

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I hope any one know where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug. Would you mind filing an [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AESH) with some details?

One workaround would be to either pass the command to `jboss-cli.sh` or use `--file=command-file.cli`. That would just skip the interactive mode.

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c ":shutdown"
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --file=configure.cli`
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using VirtualBox + Centos 7 image, not able to reproduce the problem. Knowing what is the output of "stty -a", the value of TERM and LANG env var would help understand what is going on.
Thank you.
JF